# How to get the close icon(cross sign) at top right corner of modal in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-design-system

I am creating a modal and copied the code of modal from Salesforce Lightning Design System. Here is the code :

```xml
<section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-modal="true" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
<div class="slds-modal__container">
<button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-modal__close slds-button_icon-inverse">
<svg class="slds-button__icon slds-button__icon_large" aria-hidden="true">
<use xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#close"></use>
</svg>
<span class="slds-assistive-text">Cancel and close</span>
</button>
<div class="slds-modal__header">
<h1 id="modal-heading-01" class="slds-modal__title slds-hyphenate">Modal header</h1>
</div>
<div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium" id="modal-content-id-1">
<p>Sit nulla est ex deserunt exercitation anim occaecat. Nostrud ullamco deserunt aute id consequat veniam incididunt duis in sint irure nisi. Mollit officia cillum Lorem ullamco minim nostrud elit officia tempor esse quis. Cillum sunt ad dolore quis
aute consequat ipsum magna exercitation reprehenderit magna. Tempor cupidatat consequat elit dolor adipisicing.</p>
<p>Dolor eiusmod sunt ex incididunt cillum quis nostrud velit duis sit officia. Lorem aliqua enim laboris do dolor eiusmod officia. Mollit incididunt nisi consectetur esse laborum eiusmod pariatur proident. Eiusmod et adipisicing culpa deserunt nostrud
ad veniam nulla aute est. Labore esse esse cupidatat amet velit id elit consequat minim ullamco mollit enim excepteur ea.</p>
</div>
<div class="slds-modal__footer">
<button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral" aria-label="Cancel and close">Cancel</button>
<button class="slds-button slds-button_brand">Save</button>
</div>
</div>
</section>
<div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open" role="presentation"></div>
```

in the 5th line they are using some link to get the icon `<use xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#close"></use>` but the icon is not visible.
How to get the close sign at top right corner of modal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use the lightning icon instead of svg like shown below

```
<lightning-icon
    icon-name="utility:close"
    size="large"
    alternative-text="Indicates close"
>
</lightning-icon>
```

Comment: It's important that the `lightning-icon` includes an `onclick` handler to ensure that this will close the modal. This may invoke the same JavaScript function as is used for a `Close` button on the modal...